# Pure virtual functions with arguments of the same class

Tags: c++

I'd appreciate if anyone could enlighten me what is going on here: Say I declare the following

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void member(Base b) = 0;
};
```

which give the following compiler error:

```
pvf.cpp:3:18: error: cannot declare parameter ‘b’ to be of abstract type ‘Base’
     virtual void member(Base b) = 0;
              ^
pvf.cpp:1:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Base’:
     class Base {
   ^
pvf.cpp:3:18: note:     virtual void Base::member(Base)
     virtual void member(Base b) = 0;
```

However, if I pass by reference, it compiles without problems:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void member(Base& b) = 0;
};
```

Furthermore, I'd like to implement member() in the derived class as

```
class Base {
public:
virtual void member(Base& b) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void member(Derived& d) {};
};

int main() {
    Derived d;
}
```

However, (obviously?) I get

```
pvf.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
pvf.cpp:12:14: error: cannot declare variable ‘d’ to be of abstract type ‘Derived’
    Derived d;
    ^
pvf.cpp:6:8: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Derived’:
    class Derived : public Base {
    ^
pvf.cpp:3:15: note:     virtual void Base::member(Base&)
    virtual void member(Base& b) = 0;
```

Comment: If you declare `member(Base b)` (without the reference), that means every time someone calls `member`, the parameter will be passed by value and copied (and if the object being passed is actually a `Derived`, it will get *sliced* during the copy).

Comment: Yes. All as expected. Use `Base&`. What's your question?

Answer (score 4):

Your first function

```
virtual void member(Base b) = 0;
```

takes a parameter of class `Base` by value which requires an **instance** of `Base` to be passed to it. But as `Base` is an abstract class (because it contains a pure virtual function) it cannot be instantiated and therefore you cannot create an instance of `Base` to pass to it! That is the reason for your first error.

In your second case, in your derived class you declare a function

```
void member(Derived& d) {};
```

which you may think overrides the base class virtual function

```
virtual void member(Base& b) = 0;
```

but it does not (it in fact, hides it - see [Why does a virtual function get hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146499/why-does-a-virtual-function-get-hidden) for an explanation of this), and so `Derived` remains abstract class because you have **not** provided an implementation of the pure virtual function in the base class. For this reason `Derived` also cannot be instantiated. Derived classes that fail to provide an implementation for a base class pure virtual function will remain abstract just like the base class.

Comment: Thanks! What I am trying to achieve is a base class that forces all its derived classes to implement a pass-by-value method Derived::member(Derived d). Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: @user: We'd have to know more about your specific application to determine if this is "wrong" or not, but it's certainly possible using the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP): `template<typename TDerived> class Base { public: virtual void member(TDerived b) = 0; }; class Derived : Base<Derived> { ... };`. This is probably not what you really want, though...

Comment: I am writing some statistical software, and I'd like to be able to do something like Distribution::sample(Parameters p) in the general code, but I'd like to be able to plug in the type of distribution at run-time, such as Gaussian::sample(NormalParam p) etc., where Gaussian derives from Distribution and NormalParam derives from Parameters, and I'd like to assert that all distributions implement ::sample(). An Observation class requires me to pass an object of the same class to a method. The passing-by-value is just a curiosity I stumbled upon, and not a requirement - always trying to learn ;-)

Comment: Use references to bases.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit, please (sorry if you're saying something obvious - I'm a really a noob when it comes to C++...)