# C++ Function Overloading (Understanding why this case is ambiguous)

Tags: c++

I have a head cold so it may be that I am simply too congested to understand what is going on here but I can't figure out how the following doesn't compile?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Base {

public:
    virtual void foo(const std::string & data) {
        foo(data.data(), data.size());
    }
    virtual void foo(const void * bytes, int size) = 0;

};

class Derived : public Base{

public:
    virtual void foo(const void * bytes, int size) {
        std::cout << "Num Bytes: " << size << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Derived x;
    std::string blah = "Hello";
    x.foo(blah);
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
./foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
./foo.cpp:25:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘Derived::foo(std::__cxx11::string&)’
     x.foo(blah);
               ^
./foo.cpp:17:18: note: candidate: virtual void Derived::foo(const void*, int)
     virtual void foo(const void * bytes, int size) {
                  ^
./foo.cpp:17:18: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

If I rename the first instance of `foo` to `fooString` then everything works so it seems the second instance of `foo` is somehow hiding the first.  However, given that the second instance has two arguments instead of one I can't figure out how it would be ambiguous.

UPDATE: It also works fine without the inheritance (if it is all one class) so I suspect I am misunderstanding some rule of inheritance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146499/why-does-a-virtual-function-get-hidden

Comment: @latedeveloper thanks, that explains it nicely.

Comment: that works `x.Base::foo(blah);`

Answer (score 2):

Your `virtual void foo(const void * bytes, int size)` function inside `Derived` class expects two parameters but when calling this function `x.foo(blah);` from `main` you are passing only one parameter `blah`.

You need to pass two parameters in to the function call as your `foo`function inside `Derived` class expects.

Alternatively if you want to call the `foo` function of `Base` class, try `x.Base::foo(blah);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is **not** that the functions are ambiguous! Instead, the problem is that the overwrite in `Derived` actually hides the base class function(s)! If you want to avoid this hiding, you *can* make the base class versions available with a `using`-declaration:

```
class Derived: public Base {
    // ...
public:
     using Base::foo;
     void foo(void const* bytes, int size) override {
        // ...
     }
};
```

Alternatively you can explicitly call the base class function using qualification at the call site:

```
x.Base::foo(blah);
```

To avoid the need of having derived classes do something special when they override a `virtual` function you are best off using the approach of having the `virtual` functions be `protected` and have `public` function delegating to these (this approach is consistently used for `virtual` functions in the standard C++ library), e.g.:

```
class Base {
protected:
    virtual void do_foo(std::string const& s) {
        this->foo(s.c_str(), s.size());
    }
    virtual void do_foo(void const* bytes, int size) = 0;
public:
    void foo(std::string const& s) { this->do_foo(s); }
    void foo(void const* bytes, int size) { this->do_foo(bytes, size); }
};
```

... and then override `do_foo()` appropriately in derived classes.